# Populate Gridview at runtime using textfile

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

it may seem to be simple problem to many of you, but want i am trying to do is i am reading a text file on a click event using `StreamReader` (ASP.net & C#) after reading that text file i am splitting each line with ',' delimiter and then each part of it i am storing in `Datatable's` column and then binding the datatable to my gridview, my problem is i have written the code but i m getting empty gridview like this

[image]
Gridviews Column header i have created from designer with `autogeneratecolumns="false"`

my code is

```
protected void readfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\fileread\readtext.txt"))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(',');
            dt.Rows.Add();
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add();
                dt.Rows[0][i] = parts[i];
                MyGridView.DataSource = dt;
                MyGridView.DataBind();
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
```

my text file has data

```
1,1,4,2,"#",Description1
5,5,4,2,"#",Description2
3,3,6,3,"#",Description3
2,2,4,2,"#",Description4
4,5,4,2,"#",Description5
```

Hope you got it what i am trying to ask.

Comment: post your aspx markup for gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    protected void readfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Row No.");
        table.Columns.Add("Col No.");
        table.Columns.Add("Width");
        table.Columns.Add("Height");
        table.Columns.Add("Image URL");
        table.Columns.Add("Description");

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\fileread\readtext.txt"))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] parts = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                table.Rows.Add(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
            }
        }
        MyGridView.DataSource = table;
        MyGridView.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, one small change if i want to make that is instead of giving a static path for streamreader to read, how can i read the with OpenFileDialog and do the same thing of adding and binding table.

Comment: You first need to understand that asp.net is different to windows forms development,you can't use an open file dialog.You first need to  send the file through to the server and then do further processing.Do a google search for - using fileupload in asp.net it will return many examples on how this can be done

Comment: Can I use this method in c# winform too? please advise.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should move your code with [adding the `DataColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55b10992.aspx) outside the `for`-loop
2. You should create new `DataRow` using [`DataTable.NewRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx) method
3. You should call data binding methods only once, and after the loops.

Your code should be something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Row No", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Col No", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Width", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Height", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("ImageUrl", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(String));

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\fileread\readtext.txt"))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(',');
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            row[i] = parts[i];
        }
        // important thing!
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    sr.Close();
}
MyGridView.DataSource = dt;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, one small change if i want to make that is instead of giving a static path for streamreader to read, how can i read the with OpenFileDialog and do the same thing of adding and binding table.

Answer (score 1):

Add columns to datatable using code below

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Row No", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Col No", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Width", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Height", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("ImageUrl", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(String));
```

And bind datatable (dt) after you populate all rows in datatable, after while loop

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\fileread\readtext.txt"))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(',');
        var dr = dt.NewRow(); //use newrow to create new row
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = parts[i];
        }
        
        dt.Rows.Add(dr); //add row to datatable now
    }
    sr.Close();
}
//bind datatable to Gridview after we load file into dt
MyGridView.DataSource = dt;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, one small change if i want to make that is instead of giving a static path for streamreader to read, how can i read the with OpenFileDialog and do the same thing of adding and binding table.