# StreamReader with tab delimited text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, split, streamreader, csv

I have a similar requirement to this post...
[Populate Gridview at runtime using textfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971165/populate-gridview-at-runtime-using-textfile)

Where I want to read a text file with `StreamReader` and populate a `DataTable` with the data in the file, however I'm not sure how to implement a `split()` with a tab.

Could anybody point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: sr.ReadLine().Split("\t"); used in vb not sure about this.

Comment: Fields are delimited by tab, how are rows delimited? By newline?

Comment: new rows are new lines. this is a fairly simple and standard edi file layout that i am trying to read and display to the end user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("col1");
        table.Columns.Add("col2");
        table.Columns.Add("col3");

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data.txt").ToList();
        lines.ForEach(line => table.Rows.Add(line.Split((char)9)));
```

I presumed that rows are delimited by newline (if that's the case `ReadAllLines` method can be used). Number 9 is the ASCII value for horizontal tab character and it is used for splitting the line. `ForEach` is a method that can be used on generic lists, it is there instead of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out today and check back on how I get on. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The escape character for a tab in C# is `\t`, so to read a file and split each line on a tab I'd use

```
var path = "path to file";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        //Reads the line, splits on tab and adds the components to the table
        table.Rows.Add(sr.ReadLine().Split('\t'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only tab characters you can use Split('\t'), but if the tabs are white spaces you might want to use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)