# asp.net folder access

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-permissions

I'm trying to read a file that's just been uploaded to the server, in a newly created folder (folder name is the session id)

> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path '...\UploadFiles\jeiqw1qxya33e3r00idwlceo' is denied.

I'm not sure what user to give access to, looking on the net it says to add the identity that the Application Pool runs under, which for me looks to me ApplicationPoolIdentity... but I can't find this user to add to the folder permissions. So I added "everyone" and gave full control... just to experiment mind, and I still get the error above.

This is related to my last question here... 
[StreamReader with tab delimited text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954437/streamreader-with-tab-delimited-text-file/14954905#14954905)

using the '`File.ReadAllLines()`' method, this is the line that has the exception.

Comment: I would check what permissions are currently assigned to that folder.  Also make sure the folder is inheriting permissions

Comment: Make sure the actual file's permissions are set to Everyone:Full Control (to experiment).

Answer (score 0):

It is not practical to give read access to a folder created dynamically - as you said folder name is session id.

However, you can stream the file back to a user like this.

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.Charset = "utf-8";
response.ContentType = "text/xls";
response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
   string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running IIS 7.5 or higher the user which your app pool runs with is usually "IIS APPPool{POOL NAME}" where {POOL NAME} is the name of the pool/site.

If you're using IIS 7 with application pool identity I think it's still 'NETWORK SERVICE' that your site runs with.

Btw you can directly see the user that yoru apppool(w3wp.exe) is running in a tool like task manager/process explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find out which specific account the application is running under is in code: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

But if you have given that account, or everyone, full control and you are still getting access denied errors, is it possible that the newly uploaded file is locked?  Are you saving the uploaded file to a location that's inside a virtual directory?  Sometimes IIS can temporarily lock a file if it's saved to a browsable location.  Virus scanners can also sometimes cause file locking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank everyone for their responses.

When I looked at the code this morning with fresh eyes, I noticed a mistake in my code...

I had...

```
var records = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/") + Session.SessionID).ToList();
```

which points to the folder, and not a target file.

I changed to...

```
var records = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/") + Session.SessionID + "/ediFile.txt").ToList();
```

This now works! It's no wonder this confused me as the permission set up is correct after all! :)