# How to read .txt file into data gridview using c#?

Tags: c#, gridview, readfile

so I'm new to c# and I was given an assignment (without being taught) to read a .txt file into a data gridview. I did it using StreamReader but it was rejected. It makes up 30% of my grade and I can't figure it out.
text file:
[image]

I'm required to put the date in one column, time in another, userID in another and the message in another. Almost any information will be helpful right about now

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971165/populate-gridview-at-runtime-using-textfile

Comment: 'rejected' - do you mean it didnt work or the teacher said he didnt like it

Comment: why was  it rejected?

Comment: Rejected because he did not want the file to be read using StreamReader. It worked perfectly

Comment: well...what DID he want?  you have to be able to read the file before anything else.  There must be some method he taught in class that he wants you to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to parse every line into an attribute of a Tuple. You could read the file a line at a time and split it by space as a delimiter.
2. Create a list of tuples. Add every Tuple you have parsed into the list.
3. Bind this collection to the ItemsSource property or DataSource property of the grid.